# How to get the html of certain tag using php DomDocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument

first I let the it find the element

```
$dom= new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$only_p = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(1);
```

If I try something like

```
$only_p->textContent; /* <-- it will only return the text inside the paragraph and even remove all the tags inside of it */
```

what I need is something like

```
$only_p = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(1);
$only_p->outerHTML;
```

that would return the HTML around it, like

```
<p class="something"><a href="link"> this is text </a></p>
```

instead of just the string "this is text"

Comment: You can try `$only_p->ownerDocument->saveXML($only_p);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it

```
/**
 * Returns the outer HTML of a certain tag.
 * You can decide whether the result should be returned as string or inside an array.
 *
 * @param $html_string
 * @param $tagName
 * @param string $return_as
 * @return array|string
 */
public function getOuterHTMLFromTagName($html_string,$tagName,$return_as='array')
{
    //create a new DomDocument based on the first parameter's html
    $dom_doc= new \DOMDocument();
    $dom_doc->loadHTML($html_string);

    //set variables for the result type
    $html_results_as_array = array();
    $html_results_as_string = "";

    // get tags from DocDocument
    $elements_in_tag =$dom_doc->getElementsByTagName($tagName);

    // loop through found tags
    for($a=0; $a < $elements_in_tag->length; $a++)
    {
        // get tag of current key
        $element_in_tag = $dom_doc->getElementsByTagName($tagName)->item($a);

        //create a new DomDocument that only contains the tags HTML
        $element_doc = new \DOMDocument();
        $element_doc->appendChild($element_doc->importNode($element_in_tag,true));

        //save the elements HTML in variables
        $html_results_as_string .= $element_doc->saveHTML();
        array_push($html_results_as_array,$element_doc->saveHTML());
    }

    //return either as array or string
    if($return_as == 'array')
    {
        return $html_results_as_array;
    }
    else
    {
        return $html_results_as_string;
    }
}
```